# angular 2 parent and child detect changes hierarchy

Tags: angular

I am trying to solve "Expression has changed after it was checked" issue.

I have a parent component who has an undefined/empty array.
this array is attached to ngFor directive.

There is a child component which fill the parent array via event emitter (output()).
when the child component does the emit on **Every lifecycle hook**, I get the error.
when the child component does the emit on click, it works fine.

Where should I emit this array from the child to the parent in a way that angular will feel good about detecting the changes?

parent (check out the pageArr variable):

```
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let el of pageArr; let i=index">
        x={{el.x}}
        y={{el.y}}
      </div>
      <my-pag [list]="arr" (pageList)="pageArr = $event"></my-pag>
```

child

```
ngOnInit(){
       this.pageList.emit([{x:1,y:10}]);
  }
```

[plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uNX8ypJdatakc8EDQA7g?p=preview)

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: I added a sample of code. the error is at the console

Comment: just found out that using the setTimeout function solves the problem, but I don't understand what is going on. why change detection explode when using the lifecycle hooks?